# WildFly - Global session expiry across multiple application contexts

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, jboss, single-sign-on, wildfly

We have multiple application contexts deployed on WildFly.

Is it possible to have a global session expiry across all deployed applications so that if 1 application's session state has not expired, the rest of the application's session state cannot expire? Could this be achieved through configuring Single Sign On?

We would like to have the same behaviour as a portal containing many portlets where there is a portal session scope that contains portlets with their own session scope. The session expiry would correspond to inactivity within the portal session scope.

Please let me know if anyone out there has achieved what I've described above (but not with a Portal architecture).

Answer (score 0):

Every application sets its session timeout in the `web.xml` each of them maintains sessions for users independent of the other applications in the server and this is the behavior all Java EE application servers by my experience. That said, if you configure SSO i will advice you set the same session timeout for all these applications in the `web.xml` and you can be sure of common session timeout.

Comment: Hi Tunde, Configuring the session timout in web.xml only addresses session timeout for each individual application session, however we would like the scope to be for all applications being served by wildfly. When using SSO, if it still uses the session timeout values in web.xml for each individual application, I don't think this solution would work for us.

Comment: I found this on [JbossDeveloper](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242039?_sscc=t). Go through it might help. You might have to settle for a workaround.